# Win 10 Netflix app bug : constant 100% volume

Tags: windows-10, netflix

This bug has been raging on for 2 months now - lowering the sound through the Netflix app wouldn't work, the volume would stay at 100%. Only lowering windows master volume helps.

Same thing happens on my other pc. Has anyone experienced the same bug and found a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce on my Windows 10 Version 1607 machine,

Comment: I've been able to reproduce on a Windows 10 Version 2009.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved this issue by disabling "Exclusive Mode" for the playback device.

Step by step:

1. Right click on the taskbar volume icon
2. playback devices
3. right click on your default audio device
4. properties
5. Advanced Tab
6. uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"
7. Apply

Comment: Thank you! I also had to restart Netflix after having done this for it to work.